# NEO4j - Cypher - Activity Feed - multiple left join, pivot table/crosstab, for optional nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher

How do I make the equivalent of a this left join in cypher, but returning a single row for each activity?  (Assume only 1 optional target record and one optional source record per activity - both can be present or absent etc)

```
person-----activity--+--> source (optional table, left join)
                     +--> target(optional table, left join)
```

of course I don't want two rows if a source and target exists, so this would be rolled up via crosstab /pivot table query so the final row would be

```
person...activity...(optional source node)...(optional target node)
```

I want to bring back the person, activity, and optionally the source and target rows if they even exist - if not, just the person and activity.. I want one row per activity.

See the graph example at: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rogg0w

Here is my guess as how to accomplish this

```
start n=node(1)
match n-[act_rel]->activity-[?sourcerel]-(source)
with n
match n-[act_rel]->activity-[?targetrel]-(target)
return n, activity, source.description! as description, target.description! as target_description
```

Basically I'd like to bring back a person's list of activities with optional source and target nodes on a single row for each activity - is this possible to do through Cyhper alone? (Using ROR / REST).  What is wrong with the Cypher query above?  Or must I get the person and activity data from cyper, and then look up nodes individually via code which would be, IMO, a big performance hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comma to specify multiple parts of a pattern:

```
start n=node(1)
match n-[:act_rel]->activity-[?:sourcerel]-source, activity-[?:targetrel]-target
return n, activity, source.description as description, target.description as target_description
```

Make sense?

Comment: Ahh.. so these don't all have to be chained in one single match, but instead can be multiple descriptions separated by comments.. thank you .. see the graph example at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rogg0w